# Converting int list to string - C

Tags: c, pointers, printf, buffer

I was trying to convert a list of integers into a compact string but I get a segmentation fault.
The code is the following:

```
    int *factors = job_factorization(number, size);
    char buffer[250] = { 0 };

    for (int i = 0; i < *size; i++) {
        sprintf( &buffer[i],  "%d ", *factors);
        factors++;
    }
```

The `job_factorization` function returns the head of the list (it works, I have already tested it), and it sets the value pointed to by `size` to the actual size of the list (so the number of integers).
I cannot figure out what is wrong, does anyone have any idea?

Comment: What do you expect `buffer` to contain at the end for the `for()` loop ?

Comment: How does `job_factorization()` allocate its memory? Also, what actual size does `job_factorization()` return when you get a segfault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note these remarks:

- `sprintf( &buffer[i],  "%d ", *factors);` does not convert the number at the end of the previous conversion.
- `sprintf` does not check for buffer overflow: if `size` is large enough, it will eventually write beyond the end of the buffer.
- modifying `factors` is probably not a good idea as this pointer should be freed after use.

Here is an alternative:

```
    int *factors = job_factorization(number, size);
    char buffer[1024];
    size_t pos = 0;

    for (int i = 0; pos < sizeof buffer && i < *size; i++) {
        pos += snprintf(buffer + pos, sizeof buffer - pos, "%d ", factors[i]);
    }
```

You could also use 2 loops to compute the size needed for the conversion and allocate the space needed.